# prudentia path weirdness: Can't find box using path relative to the current directory

Tags: python, ansible, prudentia

Prudentia cannot find the box I defined. I am quite sure that the box is there. And when I use an absolute path it complains about the `$prudentia_dir` in Ansible.

Here's my directory tree:

```
deployment/
|-- Readme.md
|-- boxes
|   |-- common_vars.yml
|   |-- dev.yml
|   |-- dev_vars.yml
|   |-- enable_cd.yml
|   |-- staging.yml
|   `-- staging_vars.yml
`-- components
    |-- api.yml
    |-- base.yml
    |-- client.yml
    |-- files
    |   `-- ssh
    |       |-- id_rsa
    |       `-- id_rsa.pub
    |-- mongo.yml
    `-- templates
        |-- api
        |   |-- logback.xml.j2
        |   `-- upstart.conf.j2
        `-- client
            `-- nginx.conf.j2
```

When I start Prudentia SSH and try to register a box:

```
(Prudentia > Ssh) register
Specify the playbook path: deployment/boxes/staging.yml
25-06-2014 18:48:35.339 [root] ERROR: Box not added.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rob/tmp/prudentia/src/ssh.py", line 26, in register
    hostname = self.fetch_box_hostname(playbook)
  File "/Users/rob/tmp/prudentia/src/simple.py", line 202, in fetch_box_hostname
    with open(playbook, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'deployment/boxes/staging.yml'

There was some problem while adding the box: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'boxes/staging.yml'
```

After a few attempts with different assumptions on what the relative path should be, I decided to use the absolute path. On that attempt the following error occurs:

```
(Prudentia > Ssh) register
Specify the playbook path: /Users/rob/......./deployment/boxes/staging.yml
Specify the box name [default: acme-staging]:
Specify the address of the instance: poc01
Specify the remote user [default: rob]: pocuser
Specify the password for the remote user [default: ssh key]:
25-06-2014 18:50:07.654 [root] ERROR: Box not added.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rob/tmp/prudentia/src/ssh.py", line 33, in register
    self.add_box(box)
  File "/Users/rob/tmp/prudentia/src/simple.py", line 164, in add_box
    self.load_tags(box)
  File "/Users/rob/tmp/prudentia/src/simple.py", line 180, in load_tags
    play = Play(playbook, playbook.playbook[0], dirname(b.playbook))
  File "/Users/rob/tmp/prudentia/p-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/play.py", line 152, in __init__
    self._tasks      = self._load_tasks(self._ds.get('tasks', []), load_vars)
  File "/Users/rob/tmp/prudentia/p-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/play.py", line 588, in _load_tasks
    loaded = self._load_tasks(data, mv, default_vars, included_sudo_vars, list(included_additional_conditions), original_file=include_filename, role_name=new_role)
  File "/Users/rob/tmp/prudentia/p-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/play.py", line 583, in _load_tasks
    data = utils.parse_yaml_from_file(include_filename, vault_password=self.vault_password)
  File "/Users/rob/tmp/prudentia/p-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/__init__.py", line 551, in parse_yaml_from_file
    raise errors.AnsibleError("file could not read: %s" % path)
AnsibleError: file could not read: /Users/rob/dev/...../components/$prudentia_dir/tasks/mongodb.yml

There was some problem while adding the box: file could not read: /Users/rob/...../deployment/components/$prudentia_dir/tasks/mongodb.yml
```

After that Prudentia bails out and fails with the same error on each attempt to start it again.

It seems that there are some assumptions in Prudentia as to how it wants to be used, I do not understand. Please help to 1) fix my situation (failing Prudentia) and 2) prevent it from happening again.

Comment: what version of Prudentia are you using (i.e. are you on master in your checkout or on develop)?

Comment: Two things comes to mind: 1. Did you check if hat file actually exists? and  2. If the system has permissions to read it?

Comment: List of installed boxes you can find in `.boxes.json` files under `/prudentia/env/*/`. Try to find the box you've probably added and remove it - it should help to run prudentia normally again.

Comment: @DmitryEvseev that's not very user friendly, but it worked

Answer (score 2):

Take a look inside your `staging.yml`. Paths there should be specified in this format:

`"{{prudentia_dir}}/tasks/common-setup.yml"`

rather than:

`$prudentia_dir/tasks/common-setup.yml`

Probably you're using box file from previous versions with newer prudentia version.

Comment: I have done that - here is my staging.yml

    ;;;
    ; hosts: myhost;staging
    
      vars_files:
        ; "{{prudentia_dir}}/vars/global.yml"
        ; ./common_vars.yml
        ; ./staging_vars.yml
    
      tasks:
        ; include: "{{prudentia_dir}}/tasks/common;setup.yml"
    
    
        ; include: "{{root_dir}}/components/base.yml"
    
        ; include: "{{root_dir}}/components/mongo.yml"
    
        ; include: "{{root_dir}}/components/api.yml"
    
        ; include: "{{root_dir}}/components/client.yml"

Comment: @user1424703 if the error is still there - you probably have same issue in your components

Answer (score 2):

Using the absolute path of the playbook is definitely the right thing to use when registering a new box, we'll make it the question more explicit in the next release.

Regarding the other problem @DmitryEvsee is right, and the issue is due to updates part of Ansible 1.6.

For more information http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-about-jinja2.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem:

```
File "/Users/iwein/projects/prudentia/p-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/__init__.py", line 551, in parse_yaml_from_file
raise errors.AnsibleError("file could not read: %s" % path)
```

ansible.errors.AnsibleError: file could not read: /Users/iwein/projects/…/deployment/boxes/$prudentia_dir/tasks/common-setup.yml

I edited `~/projects/prudentia/env/ssh/.boxes.json` (that's where my prudentia checkout is) and removed everything. Then prudentia ran happilly.

Next I registered the … box but it was complaining again:

```
There was some problem while adding the box: file could not read: /Users/iwein/projects/…/deployment/boxes/$prudentia_dir/tasks/common-setup.yml
```

Then I modified the box definition yml file to use `"{{prudentia_dir}}/whatever"` instead of `$prudentia_dir`. I also had to modify some of the components I used. I used this replace pattern: `:%s/\$([^/]*)(.*)/"{{$1}}$2"/g`

After that everything should be peachy.